# Prestashop 1.7 manual upgrade error with SqlTranslationLoader.php

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop

I'm trying to manually upgrade a Prestashop version from 1.6 to 1.7.
However it doesn't work. I only got a blank page if I try to run the upgrade feature.
You'll find the error message below.

Can someone tell me what this is about???

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to PrestaShopBundle\Translation\Loader\SqlTranslationLoader::addTranslationsToCatalogue() must be of the type array, boolean given, called in /home/immoclic/public_html/sagapolynesie.com/new/src/PrestaShopBundle/Translation/Loader/SqlTranslationLoader.php on line 84 in /home/immoclic/public_html/sagapolynesie.com/new/src/PrestaShopBundle/Translation/Loader/SqlTranslationLoader.php:101 Stack trace: #0 /home/immoclic/public_html/sagapolynesie.com/new/src/PrestaShopBundle/Translation/Loader/SqlTranslationLoader.php(84): PrestaShopBundle\Translation\Loader\SqlTranslationLoader->addTranslationsToCatalogue(false, Object(Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogue)) #1 /home/immoclic/public_html/sagapolynesie.com/new/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/Translator.php(381): PrestaShopBundle\Translation\Loader\SqlTranslationLoader->load('AdminActions.fr...', 'fr-FR', 'AdminActions') #2 /home/immoclic/p in /home/immoclic/public_html/sagapolynesie.com/new/src/PrestaShopBundle/Translation/Loader/SqlTranslationLoader.php on line 101
```

Answer (score 2):

It worked for me by upgrading the php version to 7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade the PHP version to meet the requirements of PrestaShop 1.7.
Here is a list depending on the version number:

https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/basics/installation/system-requirements/#php-compatibility-chart

Answer (score -1):

+1 I got the same error today.
I made a ticket : https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop/issues/16342

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.